# JQuery UI with Primefaces

Tags: jquery-ui, jsf, primefaces

I have some old code that uses Primefaces 2.2.1 but I now that I need to upgrade the version to 3.1.1 to use some of the new features, some of my javascript functionality is breaking.

I tracked down the issue and realized that in 2.2.1, the jQuery UI plugin was included out of the box but for some reason it is missing in 3.1.1.

Does anyone know why this happened and how can I get my javascript to function correctly without changing it?

Comment: I have fixed the original problem posed by this question by downloading the jQuery UI plugin and including manually. However, I'm still curious as to why Primefaces is excluding the plugin in the latest release.

Comment: If I recall, there were longtime bugs in jQuery UI that were affecting certain widgets.  I believe I read in a blog that Primefaces had moved away from JQuery UI for certain widgets.

Comment: I was using the dialog widget

Comment: Dialog is native widget(no 3rd party) in 3.x, we don't use jQuery UI's dialog so it's not bundled.

Comment: Hello @Hamed, maybe you could put your first comment in an answer and accept it, so this question does not come up in unanswered questions. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the original problem posed by this question by downloading the jQuery UI plugin and including manually.